# How can I print a php variable from a session in the footer of an html/jquery page?

Tags: php, html, session, jquery-mobile

I currently am trying to use print inside of the JQuery footer by writing  it is not working. Instead nothing shows up. In the earlier php page I stored it into the session using...

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

my code in my html page is as follows...

```
<?php session.start(); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Food For Thought</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header" id = "hdrMain" name = "hdrMain" data-nobackbtn = "true">
        <h1>Food for Thought</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" align ="center">
            <a href="game.html" rel="external" data-role="button">Play</a>
            <a href="profile.html" data-role="button">Profile</a>
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Logout</a> 
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
        <p>Logged in as: <?php print $_SESSION["username"]; ?> </p>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you any help is appreciated.

Edit: Problem was that the file I was trying to run php code ended in .html instead of .php. Thank you all who tried to help.

Comment: what does this footer to do with jquery?

Comment: if the page saved as **.html** than php tags won't work with that and  your session start statement is wrong in the html page it should be session_start();

Comment: I changed it, but it still doesn't work. The footer just makes a footer(black bar in jquery mobile) say "Logged in as: username" except the username is not showing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're HTML page has:

```
session.start();
```

it should be

```
session_start();
```

Comment: Changed that it still doesn't work thank you for the correction.

Comment: And you're certain that $_SESSION['username'] is populated with content whenever the person logs in?

Comment: Yup, in the earlier php page I used Print_R ($_SESSION); it outputted the value in username.

Comment: and it is the same domain (note: www.domain.com and domain.com act as separate domains)?
Other than that there is no reason why the session shouldn't be carried through the pages.

Comment: Yup in the same domain. I haven't been able to figure out and I've been toiling over it for a while. Thanks for all the suggestions. Hopefully we solve this! I can post the php code in here if that would help, but I don't think it would.

Comment: Seeing it in action might help - is it somewhere that would be available for me to go do a test login and have a look?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It turns out that you can't write php code in an html file and have it run. I had to rename the file .php